# Make 'table of contents' numerable

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

Here is my LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\input{./title.tex}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% 
    \fancyhf{}
        \fancyfoot[C]{Page \normalsize\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove line between header and main text
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\input{./ch1.tex}
\input{./ch2.tex}
\input{./ch3.tex}
\input{./ch4.tex}
\input{./biblio.tex}

\end{document}
```

*title.tex* is title page; *ch1*, ..., *ch4* are chapters content; *biblio.tex* is bibliography.

On table of contents have page number "1"
But list of figures have page number "Page 1 of xxx"

How to start extended numbering from table of contents.

Comment: `\clearpage` before `\pagestyle` probably (untested as MWE isn't M or W :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `\pagenumbering` command acts immediately, so if the (last or only) page of the list of figures has not yet ended, the instruction to renew the page counter will hold also for that page.

Solution:

```
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}
```